# Disable Safe Area Layout Guides For UIView Programmatically

Tags: ios, ios11, xcode9

Safe area layout guides can be disabled in Interface Builder by unchecking the `Use Safe Area Layout Guides`. How can this be done in code?

I didn't notice an iOS11-available boolean that directly corresponds with the checkbox.

Comment: Why are you trying to disable safe area layout guides in code? In code you can specify whether you are constraining views to the safe area or not.

Comment: `UIView`’s `safeAreaInsets` are not zero and rendering on screen when `insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea` is `false`.

Comment: Also `safeAreaLayoutGuide` is a readonly property on `UIView`, so this isn't just some that applies to xibs and storyboards in Interface Builder. I just don't know how to disable it.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way to accomplish this programmatically is to override the safeAreaLayoutGuide property.

```
override var safeAreaLayoutGuide: UILayoutGuide {
    return UILayoutGuide()
}
```

When you disable it through IB it still returns a UILayoutGuide but with zero layoutFrame, by returning an instance of UILayoutGuide, you are basically doing the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in size inspector pane of the view:
[image]