# Disabling Safe Area Layout Guide

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

As you can see from the image I want to disable safe area layout guide "red area" from code since and building my UI from code not story bored so my view can fill the whole screen
[image]

```
 let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.userContentController.add(self, name: "webpage")
        self.webpage = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        self.webpage.navigationDelegate = self
        self.webpage.uiDelegate = self
        self.webpage.isOpaque = false
        self.webpage.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        self.webpage.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.webpage.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        view = webpage
```

Comment: Duplicate to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47228989/disable-safe-area-layout-guides-for-uiview-programmatically

Comment: one of the answer in that question work for me

Answer (score -1):

You can override the property like this-

```
override var safeAreaLayoutGuide: UILayoutGuide {
    return UILayoutGuide()
}
```

Comment: I will get this error Property does not override any property from its superclass

Comment: Then remove override keyword and try again

Comment: noting change I am still getting same result as the image above

Comment: are you applying the constraint programatically?

Comment: all my UI and constraint are done programmatically I have share my code

Comment: please check if you are only using constraints like this -
let space1 = UILayoutGuide()
view.addLayoutGuide(space1)

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: the problem was actually with content view of the webKit